# Usage of "put a bottle on the fence"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Where I work there is a common saying thrown around, to "put a bottle on the fence" or the deliverable was a "bottle on the fence". It generally indicates the creation of an example or starting point so that it can be critiqued, commented upon, reviewed, discussed, etc.

A handful of us think this might be a phrase unique to our workplace, and recent discussions indicate differing opinions about how it is interpreted.

What are other folks' experience (or lack there of) with this phrase? How would you interpret it?

Comment: Never heard it.  I suppose the reference is to putting a bottle on a  fence post and then using it for "target practice", possibly with rocks.  I have heard the expression "throw rocks at it", to mean critiquing something.

Comment: Given how transparent the usage would be to most native speakers on first hearing, I'd say it could be "unique" to hundreds of workplaces and other contexts, in the sense that it could be ***independently coined*** again and again in different places.

Comment: A similar idiom used in the workplace, also involving putting something up somewhere, is: "Throw it against the wall and see if something sticks," which appears to have about the same meaning as your example: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/throw-against-a-wall-and-see-if-it-sticks

Answer (score 4):

Think of almost every Western movie where the gunman puts up a row of bottles on the fence for target practice. In effect, they are saying "Put this out there and lets see if we can shoot it down." Similar concepts are used in a lot of businesses to take ideas and have the team critique it - although most use a more constructive phrase indicating that the process is intended to hopefully take a good idea and make it better rather than just tear it down.

But when presenting your idea, yeah - you are definitely setting it up as a target.

Comment: That's the way I interpret it, to shoot holes at it or knock it down altogether. Others think "put a bottle on the fence and see which way it falls", taking a more either/or, or yes/no thought process excluding the reasoning for why it fell. Have you ever heard this specific phrase in use?

Comment: The bottle on a fence to me is always a target. I've heard expressions about "which way it falls" or "which way the wind blows", but never with respect to a bottle on a fence. But who the heck knows how the idiom developed in your company and what the original intent was, or if it became a short form from a couple of phrases.